# Opening a new window in an OS X application with Swift

Tags: macos, swift

I'm totally new to OS X application development and have some problem opening a new window from a status bar menu.

I read several tutorials and tried to follow them. Since they don't exactly fit my project, I made some modifications but it doesn't seem to work.

I have created a new subclass of NSWindowController in order to design some UIs. But when I click on the menu, no window appears.

```
//AppDelegate.Swift

import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    let statusItem = NSStatusBar.systemStatusBar().statusItemWithLength(-2)

    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to initialize your application
        if let button = statusItem.button {
            button.image = NSImage(named: "StatusBarButtonImage")
        }

        let menu = NSMenu()

        menu.addItem(NSMenuItem(title: "About MyProgram", action: Selector("getAbout:"),keyEquivalent: ""))

        statusItem.menu = menu

    }

    // open "About MyProgram" window
    func getAbout(sender: AnyObject) {
        let controller = AboutWindowController()
        controller.showWindow(self)
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }


}
```

I didn't know what to write in the new class, so I left it as it was created by default.

```
//AboutWindowController.swift
import Cocoa

class AboutWindowController: NSWindowController {

    override func windowDidLoad() {
        super.windowDidLoad()

        // Implement this method to handle any initialization after your window controller's window has been loaded from its nib file.
    }

}
```

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> [image: screen-capture]

Work like this and code like this

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate {
    NSWindowController* wc;
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    NSStoryboard* storyboard = [NSStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"Main"
                                                      bundle:nil];
    wc = [storyboard instantiateControllerWithIdentifier:@"new_window"];
    [wc showWindow:self];
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

@end
```

I think you can change Objective-C grammar to Swift grammar.

Comment: thanks! but i'm not using a story board.. could you tell me how it works if i'm using xid instead of story board?

Answer (score 0):

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "Win.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate {
    Win* win;
}

- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    win = [[Win alloc] initWithWindowNibName:@"Win"];
    [win showWindow:self];

}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

@end
```

Code like this and make subclass of `NSWindowController`

> [image: screen-capture]

Comment: I tried by adding `var aboutWindow: AboutWindowController!` and redefining the function `getAbout` like this: `func getAbout(sender: AnyObject) {
        aboutWindow = AboutWindowController(windowNibName: "aboutWindow")
        aboutWindow.showWindow(self)
    }`, but it hangs when I click on 'About MyProgram'